# How do I print out just certain elements from a text file that has xml tags to a new text file?

Tags: java, xml, text, output

I need help with something that sounds easy but has given me some trouble.

I have a text file (record.txt) that has a root element 'PatientRecord' and sub tags in it ('first name', 'age', blood type, address etc...) that repeat over and over but with different values since it's a record for each person. I'm only interested in printing out the values in between the tags to a new text file for each person but only for the elements I want. For example with the tags I mentioned above I only want the name and age but not the rest of the info for that patient. How do I print out just those values separated by commas and then go to the next patient? 
Here is the code I have so far

```
    package patient.records;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
public class ProcessRecords {
private static final String FILE = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\records.txt";
private static final String RECORD_START_TAG = "<PatientRecord>";
private static final String RECORD_END_TAG = "</PatientRecord>"; 
private static final String newFileName = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\DataFolder\\";    
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String scan;    
    FileReader file = new FileReader(FILE);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
    Writer writer = null;

    while ((scan = br.readLine()) != null)        
    {            
        if (scan.contains(RECORD_START_TAG)) { 


            //This is the logic I am missing that will only grab the element values
            //between the tags inside of the file

            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(newFileName + "Record Data" + ".txt"), "utf-8"));             
            }      
        else if (scan.contains(RECORD_END_TAG)) {
            writer.close();
            writer=null;
        }
        else {
            // only write if writer is not null
           if (writer!=null) {
            writer.write(scan);
           }
        }            
    }       
    br.close();
    }   
}   //This is the end of my code
```

---

The text file (record.txt) I am reading in looks like this:

```
<PatientRecord> <---first patient record--->
<---XML Schema goes here--->
            <Info>
                <age>66</age>
                <first_name>john</first_name>
                <last_name>smith</last_name>
                <mailing_address>200 main street</mailing_address>
                <blood_type>AB</blood_type>
                <phone_number>000-000-0000</phone_number>
</PatientRecord>
<PatientRecord> <---second patient record--->
<---XML Schema goes here--->
            <Info>
                <age>27</age>
                <first_name>micheal</first_name>
                <last_name>thompson</last_name>
                <mailing_address>123 baker street</mailing_address>
                <blood_type>O</blood_type>
                <phone_number>111-222-3333</phone_number>
</PatientRecord>
```

So in theory if I ONLY wanted to print out the values from the tags first name, mailing address, and blood type from this text file for all patients it should look like this:

```
john, 200 main street, AB
//this line is blank
michael, 123 baker street, O
```

Thanks for any and all help. If you feel like my code should be modified then I'm all for it. Thank you.

Comment: Is the text mixed content like that or is wrapped in a parent tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first gut feeling is to wrap the entire text content around some outer tag and process the text as XML, something like...

```
<Patients>
    <PatientRecord> <---first patient record--->
        <Info>
            <age>66</age>
            <first_name>john</first_name>
            <last_name>smith</last_name>
            <mailing_address>200 main street</mailing_address>
            <blood_type>AB</blood_type>
            <phone_number>000-000-0000</phone_number>
    </PatientRecord>
    ...
</Patients>
```

But there are two problems with this...

One `<---first patient record--->` isn't a valid XML comment or text and two, there is no closing `</Info>` tag...[sigh]

So, my next thought was, read in each `<PatientRecord>` individual, as text, and then process that as `XML`....

Here come the problems...we need to remove anything surrounded by `<--- ... --->` including the little arrows...There is a lot of assumptions about this, but hopefully we can ignore it...

The next problem is, we need to insert a closing `</Info>` tag...

After that, it's all really easy...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Test {

    private static final String RECORD_START_TAG = "<PatientRecord>";
    private static final String RECORD_END_TAG = "</PatientRecord>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File records = new File("Records.txt");
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(records))) {
            StringBuilder record = null;
            String text = null;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (text.contains("<---") && text.contains("--->")) {
                    String start = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("<---"));
                    String end = text.substring(text.indexOf("--->") + 4);
                    text = start + end;
                }

                if (text.trim().length() > 0) {
                    if (text.startsWith(RECORD_START_TAG)) {

                        record = new StringBuilder(128);
                        record.append(text);

                    } else if (text.startsWith(RECORD_END_TAG)) {

                        record.append("</Info>");
                        record.append(text);

                        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(record.toString().getBytes())) {

                            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(bais);
                            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                            XPathExpression exp = xPath.compile("PatientRecord/Info/first_name");
                            Node firstName = (Node) exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

                            exp = xPath.compile("PatientRecord/Info/mailing_address");
                            Node address = (Node) exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

                            exp = xPath.compile("PatientRecord/Info/blood_type");
                            Node bloodType = (Node) exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

                            System.out.println(
                                    firstName.getTextContent() + ", "
                                    + address.getTextContent() + ", "
                                    + bloodType.getTextContent());

                        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | XPathExpressionException | SAXException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {

                        record.append(text);

                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Which prints out...

```
john, 200 main street, AB
micheal, 123 baker street, O
```

The long and short of it is, go back to the person who gave you this file, slap them, then tell them to put into a valid XML format...

Comment: thank you for your help and sorry for the confusion. the " <---first patient--->" was just a comment from me letting whoever was helping me  know that it was the first patient record in the file. I myself have the xml schema. Sorry I also left out the closing </info> tag. Nevertheless, yes I needed to remove the tag "<firstname>" and only display the name john in the output text file and so on and so forth with the other tags. I see that this prints to the console but how do I get this to write to a text file? Trust me the person who created this file with xml tags has already been slapped lol

Comment: Like you do any file, check [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for details.  Personally, I would use a `BufferedWriter`, but that's me.

Comment: Is there a way to print the values from certain tags without using the  SAX and  document builder? Just code to iterate through the text file and pull out specified values  in between the tags. When I run the code it doesn't work. I can't use the SAX Parser for this task.

Comment: The simple answer is, you don't, seriously, it looks easy, but is a monumental undertaking, and yes, I've tried it before and it's just a complete mess. The question is, what's different between your example and your actual code? As the code I've provided works just fine for the example data

Comment: It throws an invalid XML error saying I can't use SAX Parser.

Comment: I found a work around to this and will post it on Sunday however I might still need assistance in printing the results. I'm trying to do as much work as possible to help you guys help me with a solution. Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: Interesting, because the solution I provided is using a DOM parser ;)

Comment: Lol yes in a perfect world the DOM solution works flawlessly. But yes I'll post the code on Sunday (I'm not on my laptop right now). Saturday I have to take the kids to a party and excercise with the wife. You know how that goes lol...Family Guy

Comment: my current solution I'm using is the one below and I repeat this for every tag I have.      


    if (text.contains("<PTNT_ID>") && text.contains("    </PTNT_ID>")) {                    
    String end = text.substring(text.indexOf("<PTNT_ID>") + "    <PTNT_ID>".length()  , text.indexOf("</PTNT_ID>"));
                    text = /*start +*/ end;
                    System.out.print(text+ ", ");
                }

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM parser and parse the text file. You can see one example in [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)